# Merging two files together

Tags: awk

Is it possible to merge two files together using awk? I have two files with matched  Chrom and pos  column

file1 has the columns

```
CHROM   POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO
```

file2 has the columns

```
CHROM POS ID REF ALT FATHER MOTHER DAUGHTER1 DAUGHTER2 DAUGHTER3 SON1 SON2
```

I want the final merged file to have these columns

```
CHROM   POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO FATHER MOTHER DAUGHTER1 DAUGHTER2 DAUGHTER3 SON1 SON2
```

Comment: Can you show us a few more lines from each file? Do the files have other headers or is it only the fields? If they're real vcf files, they will have headers which complicate things. If they're headerless lists of variants, there are better tools than awk.

Comment: Matched `CHROM` and `POS` alone might create problems if there are multi-allelic variants (or even if `ALT` is different between the two files). You might want to match all three of those columns to be sure that the variants you're merging are _identical_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to merge column together, you can use `paste` command:

```
paste file1 <(cut -d\  -f6- file2)
```

In this case the whole `file1` is taken and only part of `file2` starting from column 6.

Assuming your data are sorted, another alternative is to use `join`:

```
join -o '1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 2.6 2.7 2.8 2.9 2.10 2.11 2.12' file1 file2
```

The `-o` option allows to select column from either `file1` or `file2`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using R and either `merge` or one of the `join`s. Assuming your data is not too large, `data.frame` + `read.delim` should suffice to hold the two datasets. If not, try `data.table` + `fread`..

Comment: I'd agree with this.  R merge will work even if things are out of order, or some things are missing from one file or another.

Answer (score 1):

I did something like  below,

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1$2]=$8 FS $12;next}{ print $0, a[$1 $2]}' file1.vcf file2.vcf > Final.vcf
```

But then the output looks like

```
CHROM   POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  FATHER MOTHER DAUGHTER1 DAUGHTER2 DAUGHTER3 SON1 SON2 INFO
```

is it possible to arrange the output to look like

```
CHROM   POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO FATHER MOTHER DAUGHTER1 DAUGHTER2 DAUGHTER3 SON1 SON2
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not awk: but this is a fairly simple python/pandas script (assuming tab-delimited).

file1

```
CHROM   POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO
```

file2

```
CHROM POS ID REF ALT FATHER MOTHER DAUGHTER1 DAUGHTER2 DAUGHTER3 SON1 SON2
```

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import pandas as pd

file1 = pd.read_csv('file1.txt', sep='\t')
file2 = pd.read_csv('file2.txt', sep='\t')

# you can compare file1.shape vs. file2.shape to ensure they match
# you can also use fileN.sort_values(by=['POS', 'CHROM'], axis=1) to ensure sort matches

file3 = pd.concat([file1, file2[['FATHER', 'MOTHER', 'DAUGHTER1', 'DAUGHTER2', 'DAUGHTER3', 'SON1', 'SON2']]], axis=1)

file3.to_csv('merged_file.txt', sep='\t', index=False)
```